# css trapezoid image transparent cut

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make a trapezoid image with css. I've already found some code, but i want a code which makes the trapzeoid shape with transparent left border.

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/ucfie0ctp/image.gif]

So here you can see that, the left border of the image has been cut down. I want to do that with css. Is it possible?

So i want to make the picture with the man. It is a simple picture and i want to cut down the left border. I tried this

```
<div class="trapezoidImg"></div>
.trapezoidImg
{ 
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin-left: 100px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width:510px; 
    height:200px;
    background:url('http://iskolaujsag.blathy-bp.hu/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/getattachment-2.jpg');
    background-position: center; 
    -o-background-size: 510px; 
    -moz-background-size: 510px; 
    background-size: 510px;
}

.trapezoidImg:after
{
   content    : "";
   position   : absolute;
   z-index    : 2;
   left       : -50%;
   width      : 145%;
   height     : 80%;
   display    : block;
   background : rgb(51,51,59);   
    bottom: -90%;  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(55deg); 
    transform: rotate(53deg); 
}
```

and it works but the :after tag must have a color, i want a transparent one, but if i set it transparent, the image wont be cut. And the reason why i dont want to edit the images in a photeditor, is its going to be a slider, and i dont want to edit all of the images.

Comment: .image{border-left: 2px solid transparent } or whatever width you want

Comment: @Fabio its vertical, i need a cross border, as u can see the image

Comment: the CSS shapes usually use the vertical border to get that shape. If that is not the case, then you need to provide your code (well, in fact you always need to provide it)

Comment: Yea i know, but i cant provide it, thats the reason of my post, i waiting for some ideas

Comment: Post the code you have already found.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution...is to edit the image... **it ain't rocket surgery**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code and any tips of what you want to do in the end, i can go with this idea of gradient and image mixed in the background of a container.

On each side some content ?

[Here is a free interpretation of your unclear question](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IyiLD), hopping it will make you give us some info usable.

```
background: 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ3MT.png)   center  no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(47deg, tomato 50.1%, transparent 50%) left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(47deg, transparent 50%, #333 50.1%) right no-repeat;
```

Comment: @HofmeisterÁkos you still can use a linear gradient in your after element and lay it hover the image :)

Comment: i can make the background, the tomato, the white, and the darkblue elements, i want to cut down the bottom left part of the image with something transparent, i want it a part of a slider, and i want to change the images, so i have to cut down all of them, and i want to do that with css

Comment: I hovered the image, thanks (i thought it will be more difficult.. :D )